# HTML Editor autocomplete not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, html-editor

I've recently installed Eclipse Mars.2 and need to edit some HTML files. While it seems that WTP is not installed WSP is and I can't seem to find the difference. In any case if I try to install WTP it tells me a newer version is already installed so I assume that means WSP. When I go to "Web" perspective and create a new HTML file it displays an HTML template which is fine. My problem is that when I try to develop my page, there is no HTML tool bar nor does autocomplete make any suggestions. I seem to have to simply type everything in manually. Can someone tell me what I may have set up wrong? TIA.

Comment: What is "WSP"? Have you checked the file's `Open With` context menu and made sure the file is opening in the correct editor?

Comment: I have no idea what WSP is but that is what it says in the installed files menu. In any case you found the problem. It turns out that there were 2 HTML editors. One has the icon with <> in it and that was the default. It also is apparently the wrong one. The other is a plain icon like the text field editor and that one works. Thanks.